# How to clear the filename and value of apex:inputFile

Tags: visualforce, javascript, event, inputfield

I have and apex:inputFile tag where a user can input a filename to upload on a visualforce page. I have a javascript function which checks and alerts if a filesize is too large. After the Alert the inputfield stays filled with the file. How do I clear the input in javascript.

Visualforce

```
<apex:inputFile id="inputfile" value="{!newAtt.body}" filename="{!newAtt.name}"  onchange="checkFileSize(event)" />
```

Javascript

```
    <script>
        function checkFileSize(event) {
    if(event.target.files[0].size > 2**20*5) {
      alert('File must be less than 5Mb');
        //**Clear input**
    }
  }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass the element id in the `checkFileSize` method, and then do your processing then

```
<apex:page controller="FileUploadController">

    <apex:inputFile id="inputfile" value="{!newAtt.body}" filename="{!newAtt.name}"  onchange="checkFileSize(event,id)" />

     <script>
    function checkFileSize(event , id ) {
    if(event.target.files[0].size > 2**20*5) {
        alert('File must be less than 5Mb');
        //**Clear input**
         document.getElementById(id).value ='';  
      }
   }
    </script> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how can I make this work if the apex:input is between an apex repeat. For now it only works for the first input. How do I get the event inputfile?

Comment: @Thomas updated code to support apex:reperat7